# How can junk data be removed from text analytics

Tags: r, tm, text-analysis, word-cloud

I am very new to R and have recently started working on with on a text analytics project. I am trying to make a wordcloud of the words that make up my story. 
The packages that I have installed are:

```
tm
SnowballC
wordcloud
```

The data is that of feedbacks and contains a lot of junk words for ticket generation that are not a part of english language.
Is there any way to remove the junk words and work only on the ones that are proper english?
I have tried to make a list of words to be removed, but there are too many to be added in the list.

Please help...
Thanks

Comment: `tm` does that. If you add a reproducible example it'd be easier to help you

Comment: Removing non-english words is pretty straightforward. Download any of the massive dictionaries (like brown or reuters) and convert them into a dataframe and do `!( df1$word %in% dictionary$word)` subset...giving a reproducible example will help us give you an exact code for your data...

Comment: Hi Gaurav, My wordcloud shows the frequency in descending order as: jqxwb, gghtf, neelam, jhwqex, lkjbne, taslima, embroidery, agree, datatime...     The only relevant words to me are- embroidery and agree. want to eliminate the rest... hope this example helps understand the problem better!

Answer (score 0):

To remove stop words try this:

```
df %>%
  unnest_tokens(word_column, text_column) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words, by = "word_column")
```

I don't know if you have the text already separated into single words, for that reason there is function unnest tokens(output column name, input column name (column with setences)).

Anti join function will then remove stop words

Answer (score 0):

To remove non-english words, inner join your data with a data frame "`parts_of_speech`" from the `tidytext` package and then remove stopwords, using a dataframe from the same tidytext  package.

```
library(dplyr)    #  loads inner_join, anti_join
# load unnest_tokens(); parts_of_speech stop_words data frames:
library(tidytext) 
data(package="tidytext") # show built-in  data frames

# optional, show richness of parts_of_speech dataset
all_english_words <-  parts_of_speech$word # , > 200000 rows
grep("apple", all_english_words, value=TRUE)

# assume data-frame df containing your data was already created,
# contains column `text_column`, all lowercase
new_df <- df %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text_column) %>%
  inner_join(word, parts_of_speech, by = "word") %>%
  anti_join(stop_words, by = "word")

glimpse(new_df)
```

some finetuning might be necessary.